# Why am I getting an error while using sqrt function in c with a variable?

Tags: c

While using sqrt (n) with any variable n I am getting an error undefined reference to sqrt.

Comment: Because you didn't include `-lm` on the link line after the object file name. On some systems, you have to specify `-lm` to link the maths library, which is where `sqrt()` is kept.  Other systems do not need the separate maths library; the maths functions are in the main C library.

Comment: Did you include `#include <math.h>` ?

Comment: Please, show the example.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `#include <math.h>`.
If you are using C++ use `#include <cmath>`.

Comment: The question is explicitly tagged C.  The problem is a linker problem, not a compiler problem.